# Error en consulta sql Interbase/Firebird con python

Tags: python

tengo un error en una consulta sql que realizo a la base de datos de firebird/interbase con python.
Esta me tira un error:

```
     for rec in cur.fetchall():
kinterbasdb.ProgrammingError: (-802, 'fetch: \n  arithmetic exception, numeric o
verflow, or string truncation\n  Cannot transliterate character between characte
r sets')
```

Entiendo que es un problema de caracteres, por que el error esta al extraer el dato `SELECT ciudad.descripcion FROM clientes`, este contiene por ejemplo `Cordoba V. Allende`. Creo que el error esta en el `.` del dato, ya que al extraer la consulta desde python `cursor.execute(QUERY)`, se estan ejecutando dos tipos de datos, uno cadena de texto y el otro caracter especial.
He usado varias funciones, pero no he tenido resultados satisfactorios, por ejemplo:

```
CAST(ciudad.descripcion AS varchar(40))
```

o

```
CAST(ciudad.descripcion AS varchar(40) character set UTF-8)
```

me tira este error:

```
    cur.execute(SELECT)
kinterbasdb.ProgrammingError: (-104, 'isc_dsql_prepare: \n  Dynamic SQL Error\n
 SQL error code = -104\n  Token unknown - line 1, column 80\n  -')
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano!

Comment: proba haciendo CAST(ciudad.descripcion AS varchar(250)) a ver si te sigue dando  el mismo error

Comment: lo voy a probar gracias!!

Comment: El error era mas simple de lo que yo pensaba: `con =kinterbasdb.connect(dsn=rute,user='user', password='password',dialect=3,charset='DOS437')` , lo que esta marcado en negrita causaba el error **dialect 3 (no asi el 1) y el código ASCII**. Saludos

Comment: Si encontraste una solución a tu problema, publicala como respuesta para que les sirva de ayuda a otras personas que tengan un problema similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error era más simple de lo que yo pensaba:

```
con = kinterbasdb.connect(dsn=rute,user='user', password='password', dialect=3,charset='DOS437')
```

Lo que causaba el error era el `dialect=3` (no asi el 1) y el código ASCII.